# Quel bruit font les chevaux qui galopent ?

Tags: vocabulaire, zoologie

On lit parfois que *[les sabots des chevaux **martèlent** le sol](https://www.google.fr/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=les%20sabots%20des%20chevaux%20*mart%C3%A8lent*%20le%20sol&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=PzceV53mK4-r8wfGmZ_ABQ)*.

Y a-t-il d'autres mots pour indiquer le bruit que font les chevaux qui galopent, par exemple sur un champ de course où le sol est plus souple ?

Comment: "Tagada, tagada" ? :)

Comment: @Random -- Pas mal... mais je recherche un mot 'académique' qui convienne plutôt à un groupe de chevaux, cet espèce de bruit de fond, de roulement assourdi par le terrain herbeux (il y a aussi une notion de vague sonore qui croît, éclate et se retire). Peut-être un mot 'oublié' dans la mémoire des anciens dictionnaires, un mot patoisant ou encore une tournure poétique.

Comment: sinon, "cataclop, cataclop"

Comment: "marteler" évoque à mon sens moins le bruit que la violence avec laquelle leurs sabots percutent le sol et y laissent des traces. Me trompé-je?

Comment: @AnneAunyme -- Il y a en effet deux sens, celui de la rapidité, de la puissance de la frappe et le bruit du marteau sur l'enclume qui en découle. Les quatre fers des sabots d'un cheval au galop s'abattant rapidement  sur un sol dur (sans laisser forcément des traces) produisent un son percutant et puissant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plusieurs possibilités :

1. Battent (mais elle est un peu basique)
2. Foulent (à condition que ça corresponde aux sabots, mais ça m'a l'air bien)

Ou alors, tu peux changer la tournure de ta phrase et la nuancer, avec des métaphores/comparaisons comme :

1. "Les chevaux, galopant dans un bruit semblable au roulement des tambours, ..."
2. "Les chevaux, foulant le sol dans un bruit assourdi par l'herbe, ..."

Comment: Bonne piste pour fouler : *Les chevaux **foulaient** en rythme l'herbe qui assourdissait leurs galops* ; ou utiliser une périphrase pour battre + percuter + marteler : *Le **battement** des sabots **percutait** en cadences monotones la cendrée, lorsque les premiers passèrent le **martèlement** des fers était plus distinct*.

Answer (score 3):

Even when it’s somewhat muffled on a turf course, I always associate the sound of horses coming down the home stretch with the sound of thunder, from which you could get to “tonnant” or “tonitruant” in French:

> [Duncan chevauchait avec son armée, le bruit de centaines de chevaux
>   **tonnant** dans ses oreilles … .](https://books.google.com/books?id=18QOCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT49&lpg=PT49&dq=chevaux+tonnant&source=bl&ots=xolTleTxKv&sig=qvblZKkTBFRkd0pAM6oA78xaRkU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwr6cuqrMAhWI4iYKHQ3tA78Q6AEIXjAN#v=onepage&q=chevaux%20tonnant&f=false)

(from ‘Le Réveil Du Vaillant’ (Rois et Sorciers Livre 2) by Morgan Rice, via ‘Google Books’)

> [Un silence habituel, qui est rompu tout à coup par le passage
>   **tonitruant** d'un camion à trois chevaux.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/tonitruant)

(from Romains, Hommes bonne vol., 1932, p. 177 via CNRTL)

Comment: En effet, *tonitruant* convient, bien que je l'ai presque toujours vu associé au mot *voix* ; dans les exemples cités ce ne sont pas les chevaux, mais leur passage ou le bruit qu'ils font qui est qualifié. L'effet de *tonnerre* me semble lié à un sol dur, à un passage entre des murs qui renvoient l'écho, et aussi à des chevaux ferrés... comme ceux de la Garde Républicaine qui sur le macadam des boulevards parisiens semblent faire alors des *claquettes*.